# How To Start NX/VNC Session At Ubuntu Boot Time?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, vnc, startup

I want an NX or VNC session to start automatically when an Ubuntu **server** boots up - without a monitor connected - loading a certain user's desktop and keeping it loaded and ready until I log in via NX or VNC.

How would one accomplish that?

This code works via my terminal when I am logged in as the NX user, but not via root, and not in the init.d folder. No idea why?

```
/usr/NX/bin/nxclient --session /home/user/.nx/config/SavedSession.nxs
```

Please provide somewhat simplified instructions! I am certified linux newb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this blog entry can help you:
http://www.abdevelopment.ca/blog/start-vnc-server-ubuntu-boot

I remember that there is a Xorg Server plugin which enables you to open a vnc connection similar to a rdp session in windows with user authentication over your display manager but I really dont find the link to the plugin anymore.

Comment: the "server plugin" you're thinking of is probably x11vnc or vino, which provide a VNC server to an existing X display.  on a headless server you don't want that; you want Xvnc to provide both the X display and VNC server.  that blog link is the right way to do it (unless you want a login screen, in which case you get to convince GDM to play nice with Xvnc).

Comment: its x11vnc. thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 2):

this is how I did it

```
xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=1 /usr/NX/bin/nxclient --session /home/user/.nx/config/SavedSession.nxs
```